# Move all files from multiple level sub folders to 2nd level subfolder

Tags: windows, batch, shell-script

I'm looking for windows command or batch script to help me, i Spent 3h reading/ trying to find a solution i know its out there but my lack of scripting/programming isn't helping, hoping some can help me out.

I have a set of folders and files that i would like to bring up to the 2nd level subfolder which in this example would be subfolder1 & subfolder1 & subfolder3 etc.

> D:folder>subfolder1>subfolder>subfolder>files

```
     >subfolder2>subfolder>files

     >subfolder3>subfolder>files

     >subfolder4>subfolder>subfolder>files
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your goal is risky - what happens if the same file name exists in multiple subdirectoies? Only one version can exist in a given folder.

The following command prompt one liner will move files as you requested, and duplicate names will overwrite already existing files with that name:

```
for /d %A in ("d:\folder\*") do @(pushd "%A"&(for /r /d %B in (*) do @move /y "%B\*" "%A" 2>nul)&popd)
```

Or, as a batch script:

```
@echo off
for /d %A in ("d:\folder\*") do (
  pushd "%A"
  for /r /d %B in (*) do move /y "%B\*" "%A" 2>nul
  popd
)
```

Comment: Perfect!. it works just as intended. the files are unique so no overwriting will happen. Thank you very much. i wish superuser/stackexchange had built it "buy coffee" feature to show appreciation with more than just words. Thanks again.